# Replacing do by >>= for a scotty post

Tags: haskell

```
post "/introduceAnIdea"  $ do
        command <- jsonData
        json $ handle command
```

How would you remove the do and change it with >>= ?

Comment: The Haskell report describes an *algorithmic* way to do this: https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14. In fact the Haskell compiler does this behind the curtains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to rewrite `do`-notation as `>>=` and `>>`: (NB: a newline becomes `;` in the c-like notation option, which I use here.)

```
do { a <- m; b... } = m >>= \a -> do { b... }

do { a; b... } = a >> do { b... }

do { a } = a
```

So this becomes:

```
post "/introduceAnIdea"  $ do { command <- jsonData; json $ handle command}
= post "/introduceAnIdea" $ jsonData >>= \command -> do {json $ handle command}
= post "/introduceAnIdea" $ jsonData >>= \c -> json $ handle c
```

Answer (score 5):

```
post "/introduceAnIdea" $ jsonData >>= (json . handle)
```

I don't think that's necessarily better in this case though.

Comment: You can also remove `()` because precedence of `.` is higher than precedence of `>>=` operator.

Comment: @Shersh, yes, but then anyone reading it would also have to know that which is not how I like to write code. The precedence of `$` is easy enough to remember, but `>>=` vs `.` comes up rarely enough that it'd be hard to parse for most people I think.