# Is it possible write this code without using do notation?

Tags: haskell, linked-list, monads, do-notation

I have some function

```
bar :: MyType -> MyType -> [MyType]
```

I would like to have another function:

```
foo :: [MyType] -> [MyType]
foo xs = do x <- xs
            y <- xs
            bar x y
```

Is it possible to write `foo` without using the `do` notation? I was thinking about something like `liftA2` but that won't work.

Comment: All do notation can be rewritten with `>>=` and `return`, for this, there is even a special use function.

Comment: Right, you are technically correct. What I actually meant, was if I can rewrite it in some natural way using functions from `Control.Applicative` or `Control.Monad` and no lambdas. Rewriting by `>>=` usually requires many lambdas.

Comment: "was thinking about something like liftA2 but that won't work." Why not?

Comment: @M.Aroosi: mind that `bar` is a monadic type here, it is *not* `return (bar x y)`, but simply `bar x y`.

Comment: right, you could use `liftA2` and `join` tho.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing do by >>= for a scotty post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52147265/replacing-do-by-for-a-scotty-post)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Desugaring do-notation for Monads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019670/desugaring-do-notation-for-monads)

Comment: For this function, `foo xs = bar <$> xs <*> xs` would appear to suffice, since `x` and `y` are independent of each other. This is what you would get with the `ApplicativeDo` extension.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

we can use the algorithmic conversion from do-blocks, as described in the [Haskell report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14):

```
foo :: [MType] -> [MType]
foo xs = xs >>= \x -> xs >>= \y -> bar x y
```

But we can reduce the amount of lambda-expressions, by omitting the `y` variable:

```
foo :: [MType] -> [MType]
foo xs = xs >>= \x -> xs >>= bar x
```

and we can omit the `x` variable as well, by writing `\x -> xs >>= bar x` as `(xs >>=) . bar`

```
foo :: [MType] -> [MType]
foo xs = xs >>= ((xs >>=) . bar)
```

Or like [@M.Aroosi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52211831/is-it-possible-write-this-code-without-using-do-notation/52211977#comment91373324_52211831) says, we can use a combination of [**`join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:join) and [**`liftA2 :: Applicative f => (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:liftA2):

```
foo :: [MType] -> [MType]
foo xs = join (liftA2 bar xs xs)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may also use the following pattern for varying arities for `bar`:

Arity 2

```
-- bar :: [MType] -> [MType]
foo :: [MType] -> [MType]
foo xs = join $ bar <$> xs <*> xs
```

Arity 3

```
-- bar :: [MType] -> [MType] -> [MType]
foo :: [MType] -> [MType]
foo xs = join $ bar <$> xs <*> xs <*> xs
```

and so on.

I like this as it is easier to extend than the hardcoded `liftA2`.